# bitcoinjs-lib is installed but cannot use its functions

Tags: javascript, bitcoinjs

I've installed the latest version of bitcoinjs-lib but I cannot use the functions of the library.

```js
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
const keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.makeRandom();
const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2pkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey });
```

I get errors like:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'p2pkh')
```

Can you help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a general programming question not specific to Bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using an old version of bitcoinjs-lib. The `payments` interface was added in version [4.0.0](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400) which was released in 2018.

Note that the `ECPair` interface was removed in [6.0.0](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600) so this code won't work on the latest version either. `bip32` should be used instead.